# Different sidebar for each page in Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on a Ionic phonegap application, The Ionic documentation guides only for a common sidebar for each page but I want to use different sidebars for different pages,

I have tried some things, but still not success,

need help...

Comment: Can you access the location value of your pages like you can in jQuery Mobile? If you can you could use an conditional to alter the content of the side bar.

Comment: yes, I can access the location of each page, You mean I should  use ng-if on sidebar html.

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried that, if I do that, the $location.path() returns blank because when it set sidemenu, there is no path, It sets the sidemu very firstly...

Comment: So you can't get the location of the page in that case. And in that case I don't know how you do this, sorry.